# RoR Controllers: Create / Update methods: @record.save vs @record.errors.any?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, this might get shot down as more "style preference" than "detail question", but Google is failing me.

In my self-taught journey (starting in Rails 2), I learned to do this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    ...
    if @user.save
      # handle success
    else
      # handle failure
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

But lately (Rails 4/5) I'm seeing a pattern of using this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    ...
    @user.save
    if @user.errors.any?
      # handle failure
    else
      # handle success
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

What's the deal? Am I missing some sort of improvement?

## Spotted in the wild:

(these two are from the same codebase generated at a hackathon where I first noticed the change)

1. [events_controller.rb](https://github.com/chiperific/filterbuildscheduler/blob/f8c940fcb8417f658bc7acb527ec68cc10caf86a/app/controllers/events_controller.rb)
2. [registrations_controller.rb](https://github.com/chiperific/filterbuildscheduler/blob/f8c940fcb8417f658bc7acb527ec68cc10caf86a/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb)

(and now I'm searching through my browser history, I'll post more as I re-find)

Comment: I haven't seen the second pattern yet, I would actually recommend the first, from my understanding, the `@user.save` return value would be the same (boolean-wise) as `@user.errors.any?`. Have you checked out service objects/service classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second pattern is used a little in a different way.
When you set your attributes and use save it is redundant.
But often you can use `create` method. So the second pattern would look like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  if @user.errors.any?
    # handle failure
  else
    # handle success
  end
end
```

As `create` method return an instance as a result.

I think `update` in this approach is used more for consistency and copypaste as `update` method returns boolean and you can use the first pattern for `update`.

```
def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    # handle failure
  else
    # handle success
  end
end
```